# How to integrate Flowplayer API in Angular 5

Tags: angular, flowplayer

I am new to Angular. How to integrate Flowplayer API in Angular 5. I don't know how to integrate Javascript code into my component:

```js
var info = document.getElementById("info");
$f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
    clip: {
        onPause: function() {
            info.innerHTML = "player paused";
        },

        onResume: function() {
            info.innerHTML = "player resumed";
        },

        // trigger this function on the 3rd and 8th second of playback
        onCuepoint: [[3000, 8000], function(clip, point) {
            info.innerHTML = "cuepoint: " + point;
        }]
    },

    // invoked when player loads (not a clip specific event)
    onLoad: function() {
        info.innerHTML = "player loaded";
    },
});
```